# how to choose a security model

Tags: security, permissions, access-rights

I am looking for the best security model to implement access rights on a website. Objects access should be granted based on the following rules initially:

- User
- User Group
- Hierarchy
- Permissions (CRUD)

What are the security models I can use and what are the advantages and disadvantages of each one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control) models are sometimes categorized as either discretionary or non-discretionary. The three most widely recognized models are Discretionary Access Control (DAC), Mandatory Access Control (MAC), and Role Based Access Control (RBAC). MAC and RBAC are both non-discretionary.

But I suggest to use [RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) model. It's so useful for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) is usually pretty easy to implement and straight forward.  However I would be surprised if an existing access control library didn't exist for your platform.

Comment: Thank you but I am developing a platform-independent application, so I don't want to  use any pre-built access control. I want to implement my own.